# Can't create new Play project due to unresolved dependency - SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification

Tags: java, playframework, sbt

I am trying to create for the first time new play project. I can't due to errors sun.security.validator.ValidatorException related to https://repo.typesafe.com/*. How can I add certificate?

I installed sbt on mac and run following commands

```
sbt new playframework/play-java-seed.g8
sbt run
```

The actual result is

```
:: problems summary ::
:::: ERRORS
    Server access Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.sonatype.oss/oss-parent/9/jars/oss-parent.jar

    Server access Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.apache/apache/18/jars/apache.jar
```

...

```
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      com.typesafe.play:sbt-plugin:2.7.2 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      com.typesafe.play:sbt-plugin:2.7.2 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0) (/Users/dzejn/Documents/Development/PlayTrials/play-samples-play-java-hello-world-tutorial/project/plugins.sbt#L1-2)
[warn]        +- default:play-samples-play-java-hello-world-tutorial-build:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.7.2: Resolution failed several times for dependency: com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.7.2 {compile=[default(compile)]}:: 
[error]     typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.7.2: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.7.2/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[error]     sbt-plugin-releases: unable to get resource for com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.7.2: res=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.7.2/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[error] 
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.resolveAndRetrieve(IvyActions.scala:332)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.$anonfun$updateEither$1(IvyActions.scala:208)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$$$Lambda$2480/1497726062.apply(Unknown Source)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.$anonfun$withModule$1(Ivy.scala:239)
```

I am using macOS, sbt 1.2.8, java 1.8.0_45, sbt freshly installed with brew. I don't have JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts directory and I am not behind proxy what seemed related to solutions raised for similar problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using macOS, sbt 1.2.8, java 1.8.0_45, sbt freshly installed with brew.

My guess is that Java 1.8.0_45 is too old. The current one that I use is 1.8.0_212.
You can grab one from https://adoptopenjdk.net/ or use something like https://sdkman.io/.